# Python: How iterate list to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I should get merged text files. I have a merge_txt function and that needs list and filename, but I get one big list of files to merge.

My big list is below. It contains path from five files that should be created from 14 different files.

```
data = [
{'fn': '1_0001_01.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_02.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_03.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_01.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_02.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_01.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_02.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_03.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_01.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_02.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_03.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'}
{'fn': '1_0005_01.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_02.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_03.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'}
]
```

I am trying to understand how can a list be iterated to get a new list and filename?

A list like this should get iterated.

```
lst = ['1_0001_01.txt', '1_0001_02.txt', '1_0001_03.txt']
```

And this list should be given to merge_txt function:

```
merge_txt(lst, '0001.txt')
```

Any ideas? I have not come up with any solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` from `itertools` module to group the values based on `file` value in the dictionaries.

```py
from itertools import groupby
grouped = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x['file'])]
```

After grouping:

```py
for innerList in grouped:
    print([v['fn'] for v in innerList], innerList[0]['file'])
    
['1_0001_01.txt', '1_0001_02.txt', '1_0001_03.txt'] 0001.txt
['1_0002_01.txt', '1_0002_02.txt'] 0002.txt
['1_0003_01.txt', '1_0003_02.txt', '1_0003_03.txt'] 0003.txt
['1_0004_01.txt', '1_0004_02.txt', '1_0004_03.txt'] 0004.txt
['1_0005_01.txt', '1_0005_02.txt', '1_0005_03.txt'] 0005.txt
```

Now, you can pass these values to the function:

```py
for innerList in grouped:
    merge_txt([v['fn'] for v in innerList], innerList[0]['file'])
```

You can also avoid storing `list(g)` in a separate list which takes up the memory unnecessarily, by iterating the groupby object directly:

```py
for _,g in groupby(data, key=lambda x:x['file']):
    fns = [v['fn'] for v in g]
    # merge_txt(fns, _)
    print(fns, _)

['1_0001_01.txt', '1_0001_02.txt', '1_0001_03.txt'] 0001.txt
['1_0002_01.txt', '1_0002_02.txt'] 0002.txt
['1_0003_01.txt', '1_0003_02.txt', '1_0003_03.txt'] 0003.txt
['1_0004_01.txt', '1_0004_02.txt', '1_0004_03.txt'] 0004.txt
['1_0005_01.txt', '1_0005_02.txt', '1_0005_03.txt'] 0005.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reprocess `data` into another form where each file (eg `0001.txt`) is associated with the correct list of other files:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [
{'fn': '1_0001_01.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_02.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_03.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_01.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_02.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_01.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_02.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_03.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_01.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_02.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_03.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_01.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_02.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_03.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'}
]

data2 = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    data2[item['file']].append(item['fn'])


for k,lst in data2.items():
    merge_txt(lst, k)
```

For example, the first call to `merge_txt()` above will be:
`merge_txt(['1_0001_01.txt', '1_0001_02.txt', '1_0001_03.txt'], '0001.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

With a simple `for` loop you can iterate over a `list` in Python:

```
lst = [x['fn'] for x in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner using pandas

We form a data table using pandas with file as one column and fn as second. Then we groupby the table rows by `file` values. After grouping we merge/aggregate each group into list. Accessing this result as dictionary with file names as keys

```
import pandas as pd

file_fn = pd.DataFrame(data=[
{'fn': '1_0001_01.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_02.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0001_03.txt', 'file': '0001.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_01.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0002_02.txt', 'file': '0002.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_01.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_02.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0003_03.txt', 'file': '0003.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_01.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_02.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0004_03.txt', 'file': '0004.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_01.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_02.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'},
{'fn': '1_0005_03.txt', 'file': '0005.txt'}
])

d = df1.groupby('file')['fn'].agg(list).to_dict()
print(d)
```

```
{'0001.txt': ['1_0001_01.txt', '1_0001_02.txt', '1_0001_03.txt'],
 '0002.txt': ['1_0002_01.txt', '1_0002_02.txt'],
 '0003.txt': ['1_0003_01.txt', '1_0003_02.txt', '1_0003_03.txt'],
 '0004.txt': ['1_0004_01.txt', '1_0004_02.txt', '1_0004_03.txt'],
 '0005.txt': ['1_0005_01.txt', '1_0005_02.txt', '1_0005_03.txt']}
```

Just simple iteration through dict keys and values shoud do it. Or you can also use dataframe apply

```
df2 = df1.groupby('file')['fn'].agg(list)
# method 1
# df2['merged_txt'] = df2.apply(lambda x: merge_txt(x['fn'], x['file']))
# method 2
for file_, fn in df2.to_dict().items():
    merge_txt(fn, file_)
```